# Remove 30 fps cap Asus N series

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, fps

I'd like to remove the 30 fps cap on Asus N series laptop when unplugged. Unfortunately I cannot see such an option in nvidia control panel.

Comment: You don't see an option because there isn't a cap, the cap, is because of your hardware

Comment: Ramhound is probably right (he usually is).  If increasing the fps is possible, as convoluted as it sounds, the setting maybe coincide with your power settings.  For instance, if you have it on "battery saver", Windows can dim your monitor, reduce processor speed, etc.  You may try High Performance power settings and see if this helps with your performance issue.

Comment: When I have the laptop plugged in I run games at steady 60fps. But unplugged the limit is 30 fps. Yet the power mode is the same plugged in and unplugged.

Answer (score 0):

evga precision x 16 has an option to control frame cap feature of nvidia cards. alternatively, you can use nvidia inspector.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **how** to do the configuration.